# flatten array of object into an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const x = [{
   name:"abc",
},{
   name:"xyz"
}]
```

how to turn above array of object into an array?

expected output

```
x = ['abc','xyz']
```

I know I can do a native loop, use push to a new empty array but I'm looking for one line es2015/es6 or even lodash method

Comment: `thatArr.map(o => o.name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `map` function:

```
const y = x.map(c => c.name);
```

```js
const x = [{
   name:"abc",
},{
   name:"xyz"
}]

const names = x.map(c => c.name);
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Lodash (very similar to plain js):

```
const x = [{
    name:"abc",
 },{
    name:"xyz"
}]

const names _.map(x, 'name'); // => ['abc', 'xyz']
```

**Edit**
 as requested also in plain js

```
const names = x.map(el => el.name);
```

or

```
const names = x.map(function(el) {
   return el.name;
});
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox I did not include the vanilla js solution initially as this was already answered by #ionică-bizău and #halcyon.

Comment: I understand, I thought it'd be good to have an answer with multiple solutions in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [{
   name:"abc",
},{
   name:"xyz"
}];
x = x.map(function (value) {
    return value.name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map()

```
let res = x.map(o => o.name);
```